# Docker Container does not restart after SIGSEGV

Tags: docker, containers, node.js-addon

My docker container runs a node js application with a native C++ addon module. If there is a crash in the native module ( segmentation fault) the container does not restart. We use a Docker compose file with restart policy set to to 'Always'.
Anyone know how we should be managing this so that the Container restarts after the crash.

Docker Compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
mongo:
 image: mongo:3.4
 restart: always
 ports:
  - "27017:27017"   
 volumes:
  - ./mongodb:/data/db
mongo-seed:
 image: db_seed_data
 links:
  - mongo
web:
 image: software/img
 ports:
  - "1600:1600"
  - "8000:8000"
 depends_on:
  - mongo
 restart: always 
 volumes:
  - ./certs:/certs 
 links:
  - mongo
nginx:
 image: software/custom_nginx
 restart: always
 depends_on:
  - web
 ports:
  - "443:443"
 links:
  - web
 volumes:
  - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs
```

Docker File

```
FROM nodesource/xenial:6.3.1
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev 
libkrb5-dev ssl-cert nghttp2 libnghttp2-dev
RUN mkdir -p core
RUN mkdir -p core/parse
RUN mkdir -p /core/cloud
RUN mkdir -p /core/public
RUN mkdir -p /core/certs
COPY index.js /core/
COPY package.json /core/
COPY config.json /core/
COPY /core/build/Release/core_addon.node /core/
COPY /cloud/main.js /core/cloud/
COPY /public /core/public/
WORKDIR /core
RUN npm install


EXPOSE 1600
EXPOSE 8000             

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your `entrypoint` and/or `cmd` parameters and your Dockerfile?

Comment: Thanks, its actually the Docker compose we are using. When the web process crashes with SIGSEGV we get Exit code of 134

Comment: You need to provide the parameters @gesellix mentioned from the Dockerfile corresponding to the `software/img` image. Your docker-compose looks good to me, which means the issue can be in how your dockerfile is starting the processes which crashes.

Comment: Assuming that your entrypoint is a shell script, I'd recommend using `--init`. Since API version 1.25 you can add an `--init` run parameter (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/), which helps with signal forwarding to your processes. See https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/3149#issuecomment-341908902 for a discussion about that feature in combination with Compose.

Comment: Ah, wait - I assumed that the process stops, but the container doesn't. Do you mean that the _container stops_, but isn't properly restarted? Can you provide your Docker version?

Comment: Hi,  the web container which has the node js addon segfaults and exits completely and does not restart. The nginx and mongo containers are still running. I've included the Docker file for the web container.

Comment: The output of docker ps shows that the web container is not running

Comment: Docker version 17.09.0-ce